# Condition with @Extend or @Include in Sass

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm learning how to code in Sass (using SCSS syntax).
I'm using as example a checkbox.
Below the code

HTML

```
<div class='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox' class='box'>
  <label class='labelText'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
  adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore 
  magna aliqua.
  </label>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
// PLACEHOLDERS
%contentCenter {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px auto;
}

%AlignCheckboxText {
  float: right;
  width: 95%;
  text-align: left;
}

// Code
.checkbox {
  @extend %contentCenter;
  width: 80%;
  .labelText {
    color: blue;
  }
  .box {

  }
}
```

My question is, can I create a condition with SASS that by adding the placeholder %AlignCheckboxText inside the class .labelText, it will add automatically something to the class .box?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Conditions doesn't work with SCSS Extends (their function is to group selectors – having the same CSS declarations). What you are probably looking for is **Mixins**

Comment: right! Thank you for your help!